# How to send a longer mail with php

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to send emails with PHP, but whenever the message gets too long  the mail isn't sent.

This is what I have so far:

```
$name= $_POST["name"];
$email= $_POST["email"];
$comment= $_POST["text"];

$msg= "Naam: " . $name . "\r\nEmail: " . $email . "\r\nBericht: " . $comment;

mail("test.test@live.nl", "Website", $msg);
```

Comment: Can you specify in your post *how much* is *too long* and what is the error message you get from the script?

Comment: When the message gets long?  I've sent 2mb emails and they still go.

Comment: You should really look into something like [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html)

Comment: I think you will find that the size of the email allowed is controlled by the mail server either sender or receiver. It is not something you can control from PHP

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend that you do it this way, since emails can get spam.

I recommend you use phpmailer.

I leave you an example:

```
    try {



        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);          
            //Server settings
        $mail->isSMTP();       
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'example@example.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'pass';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('example@example.com', 'name');

        if(is_array($this->Emails)){
            foreach($this->Emails as $email){
                $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
            }
        }
        else{
            $mail->addAddress($this->Emails);     // Add a recipient
        }

        if(isset($this->Attachments)){

            if(is_array($this->Attachments)){
                foreach($this->Attachments as $Attachment){
                    $mail->addAttachment($Attachment);         // Add attachments
                }
            }
            else{
                $mail->addAttachment($this->Attachments);         // Add attachments
            }

        }

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $this->Subject;
        $mail->Body    = $this->Body;

        $mail->send();
        return true;
```

Comment: Yes thank you, but i really have to do this in php with the mail() function.

Comment: @M.Dogan Why?  That's like saying you're having trouble shipping a very heavy object via horseback carrier, someone suggests that you use UPS, and you insist that it must be transported via horse.  Unless you have a _very_ good reason, that's just silly.

Comment: PHPMailer will use the PHP `mail()` function by default if you do not specify it to use a different one.  I agree with Patrick Q. Why do you "have to use mail()".

Comment: @PatrickQ what ever his reasons, he has them. He has now (twice) explicitly said he needs this in native PHP

Answer (score -1):

I'm recommending this because your method in sending an email in PHP is very out dated now, it will save you many headaches.

1. Use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org)
2. Install [Swiftmailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html) like this `composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer`

Much easier to manage emails

Comment: Sorry, fixed composer link

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i need to do it with standard php.